# Why can Erlang statistics(runtime) be greater than statistics(wall_clock_time)

Tags: erlang, runtime, cpu

The [erlang man page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#statistics-1) says:

> Note that the run-time is the sum of the run-time for all threads in the Erlang run-time system and may therefore be **greater** than the wall-clock time

But judging from this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), it seems cpu time (runtime) will always be smaller than the wall-clock time:

> The difference between the two consists of time that passes due to programmed delays or waiting for resources to become available.

How can runtime be greater than wall clock time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say the wall-clock time for an operation is 1 minute and the CPU time is 45 seconds.  By itself, this would confirm your suspicion that the CPU time should be smaller than the wall-clock time.

However, now consider that there are two threads doing this operation, each on a separate CPU.  The wall-clock time is still 1 minute, but now the CPU time (because you have two CPUs) is 90 seconds.

The first quote notes that it's the sum of the time for *all threads*, which is how the CPU time can be greater than the wall-clock time.